# How to find a list of websites that are using the Hugo theme I created?

Tags: search, themes, blogs, hugo

How to find a list of websites that are using the Hugo theme I created? It makes me happy to see my theme used. Then I would like to see how my theme is used and use it to consider additional features.

Answer (score 0):

You can at least find the websites hosted at Github, using [Github advanced search](https://github.com/search/advanced) and a string looking like `YourThemeName filename:"config.toml OR config.yml"`